# Getting errors while trying to install tensorflow using pip

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, tensorflow

I was following these [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for installing tensorflow. I tried `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`
but am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 304, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1822, in recv_into                                                                                           
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1622, in _raise_ssl_error                                                                                    
    raise WantReadError()                                                                                                                                                                    
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError                                                                                                                                                                    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 304, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1822, in recv_into                                                                                           
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1622, in _raise_ssl_error                                                                                    
    raise WantReadError()                                                                                                                                                                    
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError                                                                                                                                                                    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 304, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1822, in recv_into                                                                                           
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1622, in _raise_ssl_error                                                                                    
    raise WantReadError()                                                                                                                                                                    
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError                                                                                                                                                                    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 304, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1822, in recv_into                                                                                           
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1622, in _raise_ssl_error                                                                                    
    raise WantReadError()                                                                                                                                                                    
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError                                                                                                                                                                    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 397, in _error_catcher                                                                           
    yield                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 479, in read                                                                                     
    data = self._fp.read(amt)                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read                                                                              
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 457, in read                                                                                                               
    n = self.readinto(b)                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 501, in readinto                                                                                                           
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto                                                                                                                
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 319, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 319, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 319, in recv_into                                                                       
    return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 317, in recv_into                                                                       
    raise timeout('The read operation timed out')
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 307, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 199, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 1064, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 924, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 1152, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 861, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/hashes.py", line 75, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 829, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 156, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 818, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 531, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 496, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 402, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I have no clue what I should do as I can't google about this error ...
Please help...

Comment: There is a closed issue on conda's [github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4587) with what appears to be this exact error.  OP on that issue later commented "problem solved -- changed anaconda2 to anaconda3"  Perhaps this will help

Comment: @Nmath, thanks for replying. I downloaded Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh  and ran bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh so I should have anaconda3 (i followed all instruction on https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip3 install tensorflow --user
```